# Java one line if does not work for prints

Tags: java, if-statement

If you write something like:

```
    boolean condition;
    (...)
    String out = condition ? "true" : "false";
    System.out.println(out);
```

It works. But if you write

```
    condition ? System.out.println("true") : System.out.println("false");
```

you get a "not a statement" error. The "correct" way is to write (the usage of braces or "to be or not to be in one line" is out of the scope of the question):

```
    if (condition)
        System.out.println("true");
    else
        System.out.println("false");
```

Why? The one line `if`s must always return a value?

**EDIT:** To everyone pointing out that

```
    condition ? System.out.println("true") : System.out.println("false");
```

is not a correct syntax, yeah I got that part. I am not asking for solutions (although the

```
    System.out.println(condition ? "true" : "false");
```

is nice.

@Andrew Tobilko where is that stated? **THAT** is what I'm interested in.

**EDIT2**: The accepted answer provides exactly what I wanted. Thanks

Comment: PS: your question seems to be changing from "why does it not work" to "why doesn't java support this feature that I just came up with". You're doing a lot of EDITs in my opinion. In all honesty, your question is no longer a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`condition ? System.out.println("true") : System.out.println("false");`
is not a statement.

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation):

> In computer science, a ternary operator is an operator that takes **three arguments**.

`System.out.println("true")` **does not qualify** to be an argument, as the method `println()` is of **void** type. Hence, it is not a statement.

Use this instead:

`System.out.println(condition ? "true" : "false");`

Comment: In all honesty, this is by far the worst answer. What's the deal with the "three arguments", his number of arguments is correct, isn't it ?

Comment: @bvdb **No.**. As I have said, _System.out.println("true") does not qualify to be an argument, as the method println() is of void type._

Answer (score 2):

**Your case:**

`System.out.println()` doesn't return any value (returns `void`). The ternary operator expects that its two parts return statements.

```
System.out.println(condition ? "true" : "false");
System.out.println(condition); // it's an equalent to the previous line
```

---

**Some theory from the specification:**

```
ConditionalExpression:
    ConditionalOrExpression
    ConditionalOrExpression ? Expression : ConditionalExpression
```

- The conditional operator is syntactically right-associative (it groups right-to-left). Thus, `a?b:c?d:e?f:g` means the same as `a?b:(c?d:(e?f:g))`.
- The conditional operator has three operand expressions. `?` appears between the first and second expressions, and `:` appears between the second and third expressions.
- The first expression must be of type `boolean` or `Boolean`, or a compile-time error occurs.
- It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a `void` method.

More information is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct syntax(Your code):

```
 condition ? System.out.println("true") : System.out.println("false");
```

This acomplishes the similar goal but has correct syntax

```
System.out.println(Condition ? "true"  :  "false")
```

System.out.println() is not an argument.. Thats just for printing. To actually print you need to have an actual string! `"example"` .  And dont forget ternary operator takes three arguments.. The condition your evaluating, the 1st result if return true, and if return false.Hope this helped!

Syntax:

```
ConditionToBeEvaluated ? IfTrue : IfFalse
```

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator should be used as :

```
field = condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse;
```

Yes, the 2 possible options, each need to have a value (which is not the case if you call a `void` method such as `System.out.println(...)`).

In your case you could write:

```
System.out.println(condition? "true" : "false");
```